# Getting indexes of undefined array elements without loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, is there any way to get the indexes of undefined array elements other than by a loop. I'm thinking about a combination of map/filter/indexOf...

Here is a loop solution what I'm looking for an alternative for but without loop (aka one-liner):

```
const sourceArray = [,1,undefined,3];
const filteredArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
  if (sourceArray[i] === undefined) filteredArray.push(i);
}

console.log(filteredArray); // [0,2]
```

Comment: Are you looking to obtain an array of indexes of the undefined elements or simply filter them out?

Comment: map, filter do not iterate over empty values.

Comment: @GregBrodzik I'm looking to obtain an array of indexes of the undefined elements

Comment: @CodeManiac `map()` sets the length of the array to the same as the source array and then iterates, so that it effectively copies all the empty values into the new array.  It may not iterate over the empties, but it doesn't ignore them completely the way `filter()` does.  ...just to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a new array with all indices and filter by values.

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) generates an array without holes and this one can be filtered.

```js
const
    sourceArray = [, 1, undefined, 3],
    filteredArray = Array
        .from(sourceArray, (_, i) => i)
        .filter(i => sourceArray[i] === undefined);

console.log(filteredArray); // [0, 2]
```

Comment: I have done this and it works, though I don't know if it is any better than the OP's basic loop.  It's certainly harder to read.  So unfortunate that the array functions in javascript handle empty and undefined elements so many different ways.  `.include()` and `.findIndex()` treat both empty and undefined as `=== undefined`.  The various `indexOf()` functions, `map()`, and `filter()`  ignore empty elements.  Very confusing and awkward.  What is the benefit of ignoring empty elements?  Are there that many large, sparse arrays where you want to ignore empties?  Why not an optional argument?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a terrible alternative, just for reference:

```
let a1 = [0, , 2, undefined, 4, , 6];
let a2 = [];
let a3 = a1;
let i;
while ((i = a3.findIndex(v => v === undefined)) >  -1) {
  if (a2.length)
    a2.push(a2.at(-1) + i + 1);
  else
    a2.push(i);
  a3 = a3.slice(i + 1);
}
console.log(a2);
```

Awful, right?  I was encouraged by the fact that `findIndex()` doesn't ignore empty array elements the way `indexOf()` does.  But it only lets you find the first instance of a value, so in every iteration you have to slice up the array in order to make it work.  I coded and tested it on jsfiddle just to see how it would look.  The results speak for themselves.